# Modifying the sort order of module in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

How can I modify the **sort order** of `modules` in oscommerce.

I cannot find where `MODULE_ADMIN_DASHBOARD_XXXXX_SORT_ORDER` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Administration Panel under "Modules" -> "Dashboard".  You can set the sort order of each item individually.

Comment: Perfect. I thought it was done throgh coding and done a lot modification in base codes.Thanks. It can  be done from DASHBOARD .